# Flag a package as being configured on Debian even if it's not

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

For various reasons, I have a package on my Debian system which cannot configure itself properly. I know why and I don't want to correct the problem right now.

However, I want to avoid `apt` *trying* to configure it each time I install an unrelated package (for at least 20 seconds). To do so, I would like to flag this package as being configured, even if it is not. That is, **make `apt` believe that it is configured**. How can I do that?

<sub>*Some context:* if you must know, my mysql database is corrupted. I will fix that later, but I did upgrade my mysql-server package in the meanwhile, and since that time, as the configuring script cannot succeed to launch the db-server, it fails, making `apt` painful to use.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is let it configure it, but alter the configuration script to do nothing. When `dpkg` "configures" a package, what is really doing is executing the post installation script for the package. To force the configuration to succeed, you can alter the post installation script to make it a no-op script.

The maintainer scripts are stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. For your example, you can replace `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst` with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

Or you can simply add an `exit 0` to the existing script.

Comment: Thanks, that's something I already thought of. However, I think one can directly edit the `apt` "database" to change that status, don't you?

Comment: @Totor This is a `dpkg` issue, not `apt`. You could hand edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, but I wouldn't recommend going that route.

Comment: @Totor Seconded. I recommend you follow jordan's suggestion.